# When calling the Var in an email setting, data is lost somewhere. - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This might be a simple mistake, im having issues with my script that reboots a server and send the preboot time and postboot time via email. Now the reboots works and the email works however the times are blank in the email, now if I type write-host $sgr11 I get the time back just fine. However somewhere along the line its not making it to my email body... Any info would be great, I do know my code is very messy and not efficient at all. I have only been doing this about a week, anything constructive you wanted to point out to help would be great.

Thanks
Cody

```
# Store all the start up variables so you can clean up when the script finishes.
if ($startupvariables) { try {Remove-Variable -Name startupvariables  -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } catch { } }
New-Variable -force -name startupVariables -value ( Get-Variable | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } ) 

$global:date = Get-Date
$global:server = 'SGSQL1', 'SGSQL2', 'appv1', 'appv2', 'sltappv4'

$global:emailSmtpServer = "exmbx6"
$global:emailFrom = "gordonc@"
$global:emailTo = "retinaAlert@"
$global:emailSubject = "Result: Reboot report for $server $date" 
$global:emailSubjectF = "Stuff Failed"
$global:emailBody = @"
<p><strong>Todays Date</strong>:$date</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Server: SGSQL1</p>
<p> <strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr11</p>
<p> <strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SGSQL2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv1</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$apr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$apr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SltAppv4</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$spr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$spr12</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Please close the Event Notifcation in FootPrints</p>
"@
$global:emailBodyF = @"
<p>THINGS FAILD</p>
"@

Function global:Preuptime{
$global:sgs11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$global:sgr11 = $sgs11.ConvertToDateTime($sgs11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:sgs21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$global:sgr21 = $sgs21.ConvertToDateTime($sgs21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$global:apr11 = $app11.ConvertToDateTime($app11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$global:apr21 = $app21.ConvertToDateTime($app21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:spp11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"
$global:spr11 = $spp11.ConvertToDateTime($spp11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
}


Function global:FailedEmail 
{
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubjectF -Body $emailBodyF -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer -BodyAsHtml
}
Function global:WorkedEmail {
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer -BodyAsHtml
}
Function global:ServerReboot 
{
foreach($servers in $server){
            ping -n 2 $servers >$null
            if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
                Restart-Computer -Wait -Force -For Wmi $servers
            } else {
                FailedEmail
                }
            }
}


Function global:Postuptime{
$global:sgs12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$global:sgr12 = $sgs12.ConvertToDateTime($sgs12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:sgs22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$global:sgr22 = $sgs22.ConvertToDateTime($sgs22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$global:apr12 = $app12.ConvertToDateTime($app12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$global:apr22 = $app22.ConvertToDateTime($app22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:spp12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"
$global:spr12 = $spp12.ConvertToDateTime($spp12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String

}


<#
preuptime
serverreboot
postuptime
workedemail
#>

<#
Function Clean-Memory {
Get-Variable |
 Where-Object { $startupVariables -notcontains $_.Name } |
 ForEach-Object {
  try { Remove-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Force -Scope "global" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
  catch { }
 }
}
#>
```

The Resulting Email is a such. Also one thing I noticed was each time I run the script in ISE it takes a bit longer each time, not sure if that is relevant.

```
Todays Date:07/10/2014 19:03:57
Server: SGSQL1
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:
________________________________
Server: SGSQL2
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:
________________________________
Server: Appv1
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:
________________________________
Server: Appv2
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:
________________________________
Server: SltAppv4
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your problem is that you are creating the email body string before the variables in the string have been created, so they expand to null. An easy way to fix that without re-arranging your code is to put the here-string into a script block, and then invoke the script block after the variables have been created and you're ready to use the string:

```
$start = $null
$end = $null

$body_string  = @"
Start time is $start
End time is $end
"@

$body_scriptblock = {@"
Start time is $start
End time is $end
"@}

$start = get-date
start-sleep -Seconds 2
$end = get-date

$body_string

&$body_scriptblock


Start time is 
End time is 
Start time is 07/10/2014 20:27:00
End time is 07/10/2014 20:27:02
```

Comment: Wow thank you!! That makes a lot of sense, that is just want I was missing. Again thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head about the script block vs body string part. I might take me a few secs I will let you know if I have any questions. Again thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome! Functionally it's not really any different that using a function, and you'll sometimes see script blocks used this way referred to as "anonymous functions".